# Inserting a node into a BST

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

My code for inserting a node into a BST is not working. When I try to display it shows only the last two nodes of the tree, i.e. it somehow overwrites the nodes in a tree. What did I do wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
public Node Insert(int value)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.data = value;
        newNode.left = null;
        newNode.right = null;

        if(root == null){
            root = newNode;
            return root;
        }
        else{
            while(root != null){
                if(root.data < value){
                    if(root.right != null){
                        root = root.right;
                    }
                    else{
                        root.right = newNode;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if(root.left != null){
                        root = root.left;
                    }
                    else{
                        root.left = newNode;
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
            return root;
        }

    }
    public void inOrder(){
        inOrder(this.root);
    }
    private void inOrder(Node root){
        if(root != null){
            inOrder(root.left);
            System.out.println(root.data);
            inOrder(root.right);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Run your code step-by-step under debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

root points to the top node of your tree.  In the while you are changing its value.  You must use anoter variable (say 'n').

The initial value of 'n' is 'root'.
And inside the while you only use 'n'.

```
if(root == null){
        root = newNode;
        return root;
    }
    else{
        Node n = root;
        while(n != null){
        ...
        }
        return root;
        ...
```

You must return 'root', not 'n', because the root don't change.

Answer (score 0):

See my comments in the code . Hope it helps.

```
public Node Insert(int value)
{
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.data = value;
    newNode.left = null;
    newNode.right = null;

    if(root == null){
        root = newNode;
        return root;
    }
    else{
        while(root != null){
            if(root.data < value){
                if(root.right != null){
                    root = root.right;
                    // root should point to the head of the tree.
                    /* Here you are changing the variable root to point to some other memory location and the reference to the head of the tree is lost. You should store the reference to the head of the tree in a temporary variable to return later  */
                }
                else{
                    root.right = newNode;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else{
                if(root.left != null){
                    root = root.left;
                   //root should point to the head of the tree.
                    /* Here you are changing the variable root to point to some other memory location and the reference to the head of the tree is lost. You should store the reference to the head of the tree in a temporary variable to return later  */
                }
                else{
                    root.left = newNode;
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
        // return temporary variable which points to the head of the tree here
        return root;
    }

}
public void inOrder(){
    inOrder(this.root);
}
private void inOrder(Node root){
    if(root != null){
        inOrder(root.left);
        System.out.println(root.data);
        inOrder(root.right);
    }
}
```